# Error 302 in downloading files Box api

Tags: curl, download, box-api

Helo I am developing for Box API. I am trying to download a file.
I already vardump the file and it already has a a correct url.
but it will just display this

```
string 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: ATS
Date: Fri, 13 Mar 2015 14:41:22 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Location: https://dl.boxcloud.com/bc/4/3e0b9dd52bc17a1edaf1c263ec613202/o-EWhPXtuelO1i_6OmSS5hOgZg0uBzXTykrrTg_ayh0ZRcRIBB15yPlDHRoYjfVRpA4Ub1dxWSCzF0pTMPVbpGD2tLBCJQF8IHoOEigMbQUIrV4C5-u-ZhJzP6uAgZxDfliI3F_Vp0WxBvjIUuKFP9wqTFJLxQHpGqA9yMH_w9-MpTQzBszWjTD9AxFyamT5MxKVDu3ak3ShkzA1xDGMiOLxMPe599zxAt_e8kuNN0stjxgQwSFsVuSR8xrqMp4VTQ9MHK4Gc2qru1zJaZy804JWGhgGUTyb6ncoG3jIrknjzh8ccM9wiKmJZKWq'... (length=1521)
```

and its an empty blank with this error. Pls help. Thank you in advance

Comment: that is a waaaay long url. are you sure that's the correct one? browsers have a length limit on urls and you could very well be exceeding the limit, causing the url get truncated. Plus, that's not an error. It's a 302 redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Box is redirecting you to the URL from which you can download the file content. This is the expected behavior. From the [Box API documentation](https://developers.box.com/docs/#files-download-a-file):

> If the file is available to be downloaded, the response will be a *302 Found* to a URL at `dl.boxcloud.com`. The `dl.boxcloud.com` URL is not persistent. Clients will need to follow the redirect in order to actually download the file. The raw data of the file is returned unless the file ID is invalid or the user does not have access to it.

**Update**

You can instruct cURL to automatically follow redirects by using the `-L` option ([see also](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#How_do_I_tell_curl_to_follow_HTT)). And here's a [solution for PHP](http://evertpot.com/curl-redirect-requestbody/).

Comment: wow. thank you so much @john hoerr. so how can i redirect the curl for me to download the file?

Comment: hi again @john hoerr. after following this 

http://evertpot.com/curl-redirect-requestbody/

i got an error "400 Bad Request nginx/1.0.15 boolean true"

Comment: should scripts be part of the redirection for example, this:
<script type="text/javascript">  top.location = '<?=$str_redirect_url?>';</script>